# Applications are not appearing

Tags: menu

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 20.04. Now when I try to open anything (applications, files..) from "search on my computer" nothing shows. Not even if I type looking for something.
I have tried the "gnome-tweaks" but extensions is available.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean, you've installed application and you can't find its shortcut into the menu or in the desktop?

Comment: No. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and now there is no applications showing on the applications grid. I know they are installed and they work but I have to launch them another way around. Can you tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> *Check these articles, please. This will help you to add the application menu to your grid*;

[Add Application menu on Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/add-application-menu-on-ubuntu-20-04-gnome-desktop)

[This article to add your application into Desktop](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/shortcut-desktop-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: I tried the "gnome-tweaks" but extensions is not showing. See when running: ~$ gnome-tweaks
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Shell not running
NoneType: None
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 217, in __init__
raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
(gnome-tweaks:2656): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 00:35:47.740: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget->priv->alloc_needed' failed